# How do I configure fpp (Facebook Path Picker) to open new tabs in macvim using a vimer alias?

Tags: tabs, environment-variables, macvim

I believe that I need to set the `$FPP_EDITOR` environment variable to be able to change the default editor that `fpp` would invoke when opening files.

I have aliased `mvim` to `vimer -t` with `alias mvim="vimer -t"`. This means that the `mvim` command should open new files in the currently available (operating system level) macvim window, and even if a sequence of files is included, it should open them in new tabs in that (operating system level) window. So if I already have an instance of macvim running and I try to pass in 4 files, I now have one window with 5 tabs in it.

But when I try to use `mvim` as the editor (with `export FPP_EDITOR="mvim"`), it opens the files in new macvim (operating system level) window, in separate (vim buffer level) windows in a single tab. So if I already have an instance of macvim running and I try to pass in 4 files, I now have two macvim "instances" running in separate OS-level windows, one with 1 tab with 1 buffer-level window, and one with 1 tab with 4 buffer-level windows.

It seems like FPP must be doing more than just passing in files in a sequence as a suffix to the $FPP_EDITOR command. I'm not sure what that is, nor exactly how to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to the question (technically) that I figured out as I was writing out the question.

But, it's missing all the right extra info about what was going wrong, so I'm going to this as an answer, but will happily accept another answer that can do more than just answer the question per se, but can give some background info about why the aliasing only sorta works.

The key though (if you just want a solution) is to use

```
export FPP_EDITOR="vimer -t"
```

and this performs as desired. For some reason it does not seem that setting the environment variable to a command that is aliased uses the aliased command, if it has an available original meaning (which `mvim` does).